# Aborting jQuery().load()

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

The [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function of the [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) library allows you to selectively load elements from another page (subject to certain rules). I would like to know whether it is possible to **abort** the load process.

In our application, a user can browse a list of items. They may choose to click a button which loads and displays additional information about an item from another document (which can take some time). If they choose a different item in the list whilst a `.load()` is still happening, I would like the loading to be aborted.

Is this possible? Is it even worth it? Any ideas?

Dan

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can't do this with [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) directly, since it returns the jQuery object for chaining, but if you change to the full [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call with [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) you can, like this:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
            url: 'mypage.htm',
            success: function(data) {
              $("#myElement").html(data);
            }
          });
//if needed, abort the request later..
xhr.abort();
```

This uses the [`.abort()` method on the XMLHttpRequest object](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_http.asp) to abort the load.

Answer (score 8):

Nick's answer was almost what I needed, but not quite.  I was using .load() to load only an image from a page.  So, expanding on Nick's answer...

So instead of...

```
$('#myElement').load('mypage.htm #myImage');
```

I'm now using...

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
            url: 'mypage.htm',
            success: function(data) {
              $("#myElement").html($(data).find("#myImage"));
            }
          });
//if needed, abort the request later..
xhr.abort();
```

Comment: this doesnt work for me...I think the problem is the .find...are there other options I can explore to grab a specific div...without using .load

Comment: does the `$.ajax` return data for you?

Comment: yea it does if I simply do $("#myElement").html(data)...but when I add the .find...nothing is returned and I'm sure the call was successful.

Comment: It sounds like the HTML returned doesn't have the element you are looking for. `data` should contain the HTML of _mypage.htm_. `$(data).find("#myImage")` is searching that HTML for the element with the id _myImage_.

Comment: I dumped (data) to screen and it contains the page I need...but the .find seems unable to find the id in the page. I have $("#google_books_result").html($(data).find("#google_books_resp")); and the div is <div id="google_books_resp">something</div>

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) manually.  It will return a [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest) object, which you can call `abort` on as needed.  In the success handler, you can use [`jQuery.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myElement").load("/mypage #mayImage", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
     xhr.abort();
  }
});
```

*Should work like this ..*

or on a another event, I send a verification on a long field, the user change the content, I want to stop the previous check to re-check:

```
xhr.abort();

$("#myElement").load("/mypage #mayImage", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    xhr.abort();
  }
});
```