# Stop all current jquery executions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html page with several blocks. Each block contains a select element that will be loaded based on the previous select. It goes something like:

```
jQuery("#select1").change(function(){
        if( jQuery('#select1').val() != 0) {            
            var url = jQuery('#select1').val();
            jQuery("#block2").load(url);
        }
    });
```

Now what I would like to do is to have a function to stop all those loads. Because let's say I've reached to the point where I'm loading block3 and I want to change select1. Loading block3 is no longer necessary and it should be stop.

Can I do something to stop all the current jquery executions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002668/aborting-jquery-load