# How can I have this have a default page loaded into the div on pageload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need this to have a default page on load of `aboutme.php` but still have all the same functionality

**function**

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.content-link, #profile-body a',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();// prevent browser from opening url
         $('#profile-body').load(this.href);   
    });
});
```

**body**

```
<div id="profile-body"></div>
```

So before any link is clicked to load into the div; the div has already loaded the `aboutme.php` page, hopefully this makes sense, and thankyou for any help in achieving this.

Comment: What's the problem? Please, explain what you have and what you need.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: So I need the `#profile-body` on the initial load of the page to have a page already loaded in the `#profile-body` so how I have it right now is that once a link is clicked the page is then loaded in the div but I need it so that without any link being clicked there is already a page loaded in the div.

Comment: And what's the default page?

Comment: the default page would be `aboutme.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this for the links:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.content-link, #profile-body a',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();// prevent browser from opening url
         $('#profile-body').load(this.href);   
    });
});
```

But you need: when the page loads,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var defaultPage = "aboutme.php";
    $('#profile-body').load(defaultPage);
});
```

And that's all. Just add this code after your code, don't replace your version.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use .ajax instead of .load (when aboutme takes some time to load)

This way you can abort the request when user clicks your content Link while aboutme is still loading:
[Aborting jQuery().load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002668/aborting-jquery-load)

If you're loading a small snippet, this is probably overkill and you should ignore this post.

If not... just sayin

Comment: appreciate the suggestion