# Abort previous stream request [GET (xhr)] after onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a simple streaming site and get to the point i need somebody to point me into the right direction or help me solve my problem.

Following scenario: The site is static and contains a menu to choose the stream from and a div "content" in which the stream should load - I use the MediaElement.js Framework as my favorited player.

This is my approach:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            $('#one').click(function(){
                $('#content').load('one.html');
            });
            $('#two').click(function(){
                $('#content').load('two.html');
            });
            $('#three').click(function(){
                $('#content').load('three.html');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#one" id="one">one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#two" id="two">two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#three" id="three">three</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="content">
            <!-- stream goes here -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My one.html, two.html and three.html have the following content (they just differ in the title, id and src):

```
<video autoplay title="streamtitle" id="streamid" src="http://any/stream/url.m3u8" preload="auto"/>
<script src="mediaelement/build/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="mediaelement/build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is that when I click through the streams the previous selected ones still stream in the background and eat bandwidth.

How can I achieve that the previous selected streams - GET (xhr) requests - stop without the workaround to simply refresh the whole page?

I already read a lot about an Ajax abort function but I'm to new to JavaScript and jQuery to achieve my goal alone.
I would appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002668/aborting-jquery-load

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aborting jQuery().load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002668/aborting-jquery-load)