# jQuery stop load() if another load() is initiated on the same container

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a dynamic website with a lot of AJAX and jQuery loading in different modules to different containers.

For the purpose of my question, consider that I have 3 buttons and one container. Clicking button A loads `a.php` into the container using jQuery

```
$('.container').load('a.php');
```

Now consider that module `b.php` is a module that takes about 3-4 seconds to load because it's grabbing content from another website and parsing it. 
When I click button B to load module `b.php`, but then quickly click button A again to load module `a.php`, my problem occurs: module `a.php` quickly loads in the container, but the loading of module `b.php` was still in progress, therefore, after another second or 2-3, module `b.php` loads into the container, even though the user last clicked button A.

So here's my question: how can I stop the loading of module `b.php` if a user clicks another button.

Note: as a work-around I've thought of disabling the buttons until the loading of each module has completed. It does prevent the issue, but it's not the desired end result.

EDIT: So I've seen this: [Aborting jQuery().load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002668/aborting-jquery-load) and yes, I can get it working using AJAX. Thanks to everyone who suggested this. I'm hoping to find an answer that actually works with load() but haven't found one that works yet.

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop - or you could build a logic using `EventEmitters`  - have you already tried anything? I guess this question is too broad

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don't see how my question is too broad: I'm looking for a way to interrupt or cancel a load() that's in progress, that's all.

Comment: If instead of using `load` to set the results directly, you use an `$.ajax` call directly, you can determine if you still want to set the contents inside the callback (e.g. keeping the last url asked and check if that is the url being returned. or by simply keeping a counter)

Comment: `$('.container').off('load');`? Would be better to use `$.ajax` though.

Comment: @LaurensSwart yes that's why i did not flag it but i think there are several different ways to solve this.

Comment: @Red this question is about the `$.load` method which is a shorthand for `$.ajax` and not the deprecated load event.   http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks @Me.Name I managed to get it working with ajax and abort(). The answer below of freedomn-m intrigued me though, so I'm hoping to find a working answer that aborts a load()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aborting jQuery().load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002668/aborting-jquery-load)

Comment: I deleted my answer as it was not correct.  The `http://api.jquery.com/load/` does *not* detail what the return value is, but does say *"It is roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success)"* which implied it has the same return value, but according to the duplicate linked above, it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a global variable and abort it every time you load data

```
 <button>Get External Content</button>

 var xhrPrevoius; // use this global var and assign it for your previously 
                  // loaded ajax when you making ajax request                    
 var xhrThis;      
 $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt", function(responseTxt, statusTxt,        
 xhrThis){
    if(statusTxt == "success")
        // do you work here
      xhrPrevoius.abort(); // abort here the previously loaded ajax
    if(statusTxt == "error")
        alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
});
});
```

Comment: In which version of jQuery can I abort a load() because it doesn't seem to be working for me. I've marked your answer as correct since the xhr.abort() does work when I write out ajax() in full, but with load() I can't get it to work.

Comment: I have made some changes to get around the idea. here xhr object is actully identical to xhr of ajax() it should work also where xhr of ajax() works

Answer (score 1):

By using beforeSend, You can abort first ajax request before sending next ajax request , see example

```
<button onclick="onClickBtnA()">A</button>
<button onclick="onClickBtnB()">B</button>
```

In your jQuery

```
var currentRequest = null; 

function onClickBtnA(){
    currentRequest = $.ajax({
        url: 'AJAX_URL_1',
        beforeSend : function() {           
            if(currentRequest != null) {
                currentRequest.abort();
            }
        },
        success: function(data) {
            //do something
        }
    });
}

function onClickBtnB(){
    currentRequest = $.ajax({
        url: 'AJAX_URL_2',
        beforeSend : function()    {           
            if(currentRequest != null) {
                currentRequest.abort();
            }
        },
        success: function(data) {
            //do something
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with using `load`, rather than doing an `ajax` request as has been suggested, you could load into a hidden div, then use `load`'s callback option to decide whether or not to copy from the hidden div into a visible component.